# Android - How to extract resources from apk FOR ONE SPECIFIC LOCALE/LANGUAGE

Tags: android, internationalization, resources, apk

**EDIT:**

See my answer below: [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) does the job.

---

**EDIT:**

Comment from Hanno Binder:

"*Apparently, the -c option is only valid when p[ackaging] resources, not for extracting them.*"

---

I try to extract fr strings from an apk using the 'aapt' tool.

I am able to get all resources like this:

> .\android-sdks\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe d --values resources my.apk > resources.**all**.txt

I would like to only get resources for a given locale, for instance, fr (French). About that, aapt documentation states:

```
   -c  specify which configurations to include.  The default is all
       configurations.  The value of the parameter should be a comma
       separated list of configuration values.  Locales should be specified
       as either a language or language-region pair.  Some examples:
            en
            port,en
            port,land,en_US
```

So I tried

> .\android-sdks\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe d **-c fr** --values resources my.apk > resources.**fr**.txt

but the outpout still contains strings for **all** configurations (/locales).

**Question:**

How am I supposed to do?

*Note:*

I am pretty sure the apk does contains fr data since I fetched apk configurations using:

> .\android-sdks\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe d --values **configurations** my.apk > configurations.txt

and fr is in the list of configurations.
(Also, I see some fr strings in resources.**all**.txt)

Comment: Apparently, the `-c` option is only valid when `p`[ackaging] resources, not for extracting them.

Comment: Thanks for the update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to achieve this is to use [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/).

```
$ apktool d theApkYouWantToExtractResourcesOf.apk
```

and this will generate a ./theApkYouWantToExtractResourcesOf/ folder contains all resources including

```
./theApkYouWantToExtractResourcesOf/res/values-<language>/
```

I was interested in french strings and found them here:

```
./theApkYouWantToExtractResourcesOf/res/values-fr/strings.xml
```

Job done!

Comment: for  `apktooAnyVers.jar` i used   `java -jar path/to/apktooAnyVers.jar  d path/to/theApkYouWantToExtractResourcesOf.apk`

Comment: Hi. Not sure I understand. What does "apktooAnyVers.jar" refer to?

Comment: i meant e.g. `apktool_2.6.1.jar` . Visit `https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/`  to make out  it's jar versions

Comment: I'll check that. Thanks!